# Can Puppet 4.x be installed on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, puppet

I am trying to install puppet 4.x on a Ubuntu 14 follwoing instructions: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/install_linux.html#for-apt-based-systems

If I use: puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
The latest version that gets installed is 3.8.

If I use: puppetlabs-release-pc1-trusty.deb
The latest version that gets installed is 3.4.

How can I get puppet 4.x on Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gem install puppet`

since Puppet 4 supports back to ruby `1.9.3`, or use the Puppetlabs apt repo for Ubuntu 14 described here:

https://docs.puppet.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#apt-based-systems

and install with apt from there normally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The important distinction is use `gem instal` l rather than `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla gem version of Puppet isn't fully supported and has some issues. It's better to use the all-in-one native package if possible (See https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/about_agent.html)

You can then install Puppet 4 the following way:

```
$ curl -O  http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-trusty.deb
$ dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-trusty.deb
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install puppet-agent
```

If you're feeling lazy, you can use my all-in-one installer script (https://github.com/petems/puppet-install-shell)

```
$ wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/master/install_puppet_agent.sh | sudo sh
```

Since then Puppet 5 is out! No breaking language changes, but a number of performance increases and bug fixed.

Same applies, but slightly different steps:

```
$ curl -O http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-trusty.deb
$ dpkg -i puppet5-release-trusty.deb
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install puppet-agent
```

Or

```
$ wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/master/install_puppet_5_agent.sh | sudo sh
```